# Probability on one try versus 4

Tags: probability

Probability had always been my weak spot, which is a shame since I love math. There was an old question on here that answered most of my question but didn’t go quite far enough for my 20 years post math class brain. If someone could explain this so I can do it on my own, in multiple situations, that would be awesome!

So, if I have a choice between one draw at 4% or 4 draws at 1%, which gives me the better odds? On the surface it seems it should be the same, but that doesn’t sit right..

Comment: What about one draw at $100\%$ compared to two draws at $50\%$? That should tell you which of the choices in your question is better. For a quantitative analysis you'd have to learn (or relearn) some probability, or wait for an answer here.

Comment: I guess my thing is this- I would like to understand, not just be given the answer. And I need to know what is expected in terms of proof I did try, because I did! I just didn’t want a massive long winded message of my hour long hunt on google. I could find how to do it for one, but not how to do it for four draws. I took calculus and did well and still remember enough to be useful, so I’m no slouch for someone that didn’t do university math.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of question it's easier to think about failure rather than success.

With one draw at $4\%$ you fail with probability $0.96$.

With four draws at $1\%$ you fail each time with probability $0.99$. Assuming the draws are independent, you fail all four times with probability
$$ 
0.99^4 = 0.96059601 .
$$

That's just a tiny bit larger chance of failure than the failure rate for the single draw. It would be hard to notice.